# How do you activate multisampling in OpenGL ES on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, ios4, multisampling

I'm experimenting w/ improving the "resolution" of an OpenGL ES based app.  Apple mentions [here](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/SupportingResolutionIndependence/SupportingResolutionIndependence.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH10-SW11) (developer.apple.com) that OpenGL ES in iOS 4 supports multisampling... and this can improve the graphics somewhat.  **How do you enable multisampling?**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The WWDC session 415 video goes over this a bit, so grab and watch that if you can.

Essentially, you create a second framebuffer for msaa rendering using `glRenderbufferStorageMultisampleAPPLE` for its depth and color buffers.  Then you bind this multisample framebuffer, render your scene, then do the multisampling resolve into your main framebuffer:

```
glBindFramebuffer(GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER_APPLE, msaaFramebuffer);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER_APPLE, defaultFramebuffer);
glResolveMultisampleFramebufferAPPLE();
```

then bind your render buffer and present it as you would normally.

I'm still relatively new to OpenGL ES myself, but I hope this helps put you on the right track.

Answer (score 3):

Or just checkout apples documentation the matter:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/WorkingwithEAGLContexts/WorkingwithEAGLContexts.html in the section "Use multisampling..."