# Implementing Anti-Aliasing (FSAA?) on Android, OpenGL

Tags: android, opengl-es, antialiasing

I'm currently using OpenGL on Android to draw set width lines, which work great except for the fact that OpenGL on Android does not natively support the anti-aliasing of such lines. I have done some research, however I'm stuck on how to implement my own AA.

**FSAA**

The first possible solution I have found is Full Screen Anti-Aliasing. I have read [this page](http://www.opengl.org/resources/code/samples/advanced/advanced97/notes/node63.html) on the subject but I'm struggling to understand how I could implement it.

- First of all, I'm unsure on the entire concept of implementing FSAA here. The article states *"One straightforward jittering method is to modify the projection matrix, adding small translations in x and y"*. Does this mean I need to be constantly moving the same line extremely quickly, or drawing the same line multiple times?
- Secondly, the article says *"To compute a jitter offset in terms of pixels, divide the jitter amount by the dimension of the object coordinate scene, then multiply by the appropriate viewport dimension"*. What's the difference between the dimension of the object coordinate scene and the viewport dimension? (I'm using a 800 x 480 resolution)

Now, based on the information given in that article the 'jitter' coordinates should be relatively easy to compute. Based on my assumptions so far, here is what I have come up with (Java)...

```
float currentX = 50;
float currentY = 75;

// I'm assuming the "jitter" amount is essentially
// the amount of anti-aliasing (e.g 2x, 4x and so on)
int jitterAmount = 2;

// don't know what these two are
int coordSceneDimensionX;
int coordSceneDimensionY;

// I assume screen size
int viewportX = 800;
int viewportY = 480;

float newX = (jitterAmount/coordSceneDimensionX)/viewportX;
float newY = (jitterAmount/coordSceneDimensionY)/viewportY;

// and then I don't know what to do with these new coordinates
```

That's as far as I've got with FSAA

**Anti-Aliasing with textures**

In the same document I was referencing for FSAA, there is also a page that briefly discusses implementing anti-aliasing with the use of textures. However, I don't know what the best way to go about implementing AA in this way would be and whether it would be more efficient than FSAA.

Hopefully someone out there knows a lot more about Anti-Aliasing than I do and can help me achieve this. Much appreciated!

Comment: I doubt that you have an accumulation buffer in OpenGL ES.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method presented in the articles predates the time, when GPUs were capable of performing antialiasing themself. This jittered rendering to a accumulation buffer is not really state of the art with realtime graphics (it is a widely implemented form of antialiasing for offline rendering though).

What you do these days is requesting an antialiased framebuffer. That's it. The keyword here is multisampling. See this SO answer:
[How do you activate multisampling in OpenGL ES on the iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3340189/how-do-you-activate-multisampling-in-opengl-es-on-the-iphone/3359467#3359467) – although written for the iOS, doing it for Android follows a similar path. AFAIK On Android this extension is used instead http://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/extensions/ANGLE/ANGLE_framebuffer_multisample.txt

Answer (score 2):

First of all the article you refer to uses the accumulation buffer, whose existence I really doubt in OpenGL ES, but I might be wrong here. If the accumulation buffer is really supported in ES, then you at least have to explicitly request it when creating the GL context (however this is done in Android).

Note that this technique is extremely inefficient and also deprecated, since nowadays GPUs usually support some kind of multisampling atialiasing (MSAA). You should research if your system/GPU/driver supports multi-sampling. This may require you to request a multisample framebuffer during context creation or something similar.

Now back to the article. The basic idea of this article is not to move the line quickly, but to render the line (or actually the whole scene) multiple times at very slightly different (at sub-pixel accuracy) locations (in image space) and average these multiple renderings to get the final image, every frame.

So you have a set of sample positions (in [0,1]), which are actually sub-pixel positions. This means if you have a sample positon (0.25, 0.75) you move the whole scene about a quarter of a pixel in the x direction and 3 quarters of a pixel in the y direction (in screen space, of course) when rendering. When you have done this for each different sample, you average all these renderings together to gain the final antialiased rendering.

The dimension of the object coordinate scene is basically the dimension of the screen (actually the near plane of the viewing volume) in object space, or more practically, the values you passed into `glOrtho` or `glFrustum` (or a similar function, but with `gluPerspective` it is not that obvious). For modifying the projection matrix to realize this jittering, you can use the functions presented in the article.

The jitter amount is **not** the antialiasing factor, but the sub-pixel sample locations. The antialiasing factor in this context is the number of samples and therfore the number of jittered renderings you perform. And your code won't work, if I assume correctly and you try to only jitter the line end points. You have to draw the **whole scene** multiple times using this jittered projection and not just this single line (it may work with a simple black background and appropriate blending, though).

You might also be able to achieve this without an accum buffer using blending (with `glBlendFunc(GL_CONSTANT_COLOR, GL_ONE)` and `glBlendColor(1.0f/n, 1.0f/n, 1.0f/n, 1.0f/n)`, with `n` being the antialiasing factor/sample count). But keep in mind to render the whole scene like this and not just this single line.

But like said this technique is completely outdated and you should rather look for a way to enable MSAA on your ES platform.