# GLKViewDrawableMultisample4X not working on device?

Tags: ios, ipad, opengl-es, glkit

When I set view.drawableMultisample = GLKViewDrawableMultisample4X, the lines(edges of the triangles) are antialiased, but not the output of the fragmentshader(inside of the triangles).

Is this how it's supposed to work?

On the iPad simulator, the whole screen(including fragmentshader) is antialiased.
My device is an iPad3.

EDIT:
Screenshots are here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gbEdt.jpg

Comment: actually it should work exactly the same if you create second framebuffer by yourself. For example:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3340189/how-do-you-activate-multisampling-in-opengl-es-on-the-iphone

Comment: `GLKView` does exactly the same thing to set up and resolve its multisampling buffer (you can tell by examining the sequence of OpenGL ES calls in an Xcode frame capture), so that's not the problem. Maybe you could post some pictures of your device vs simulator output?